# How to get id of html element in top level html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

After rendering the html and jquery code in the browser,

```
 <html>
  <body>
   ...
   <div class="mce-container-body">
   <div class="mce-first">
    ...
    <input type="text" id="texteditfirst01">
    ...
     </div> 
      <div class="mce-last">
    <input type="text" id="texteditsecond01">
    </div> 
</div>
<iframe>
    <html>
    ...
          <input type="submit" onclick="return mySubmit();" />

 <script type="text/javascript">

     function mySubmit() {
         var URL = "http://localhost:61222/14CommunityImages/hands.png";
         var id = window.parent.$(".mce-container-body").child("input").attr("id");
         alert(id);
         //parent.document.getElementById("mceu_96-inp").value = URL;
         tinyMCEPopup.close();
     }

</script>

    ...
    </html>
</iframe>

  </body>
  </html>
```

in the above lines of code, it is not able to retrieve id of mce-first's input tag. Please help me !!!

Note that id is changed dynamically at different run time, that i have to first fetch the corresponding of of input tag...

Here is the browser version of code

```
<div id="mceu_121-body" class="mce-container-body mce-abs-layout" style="width: 485px; height: 180px;"><div id="mceu_121-absend" class="mce-abs-end"></div><div id="mceu_122" class="mce-container mce-panel mce-first mce-last mce-abs-layout-item" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 485px; height: 180px;"><div id="mceu_122-head" class="mce-tabs" role="tablist"><div id="mceu_122-t0" class="mce-tab mce-active" unselectable="on" role="tab" aria-controls="mceu_123" aria-selected="true" tabindex="-1">General</div><div id="mceu_122-t1" class="mce-tab" unselectable="on" role="tab" aria-controls="mceu_131" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1">Advanced</div></div><div id="mceu_122-body" class="mce-container-body mce-abs-layout" style="width: 485px; height: 150px;"><div id="mceu_122-absend" class="mce-abs-end"></div><div id="mceu_123" class="mce-container mce-form mce-first mce-abs-layout-item" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="mceu_122-t0" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 485px; height: 150px;"><div id="mceu_123-body" class="mce-container-body mce-abs-layout" style="width: 485px; height: 150px;"><div id="mceu_123-absend" class="mce-abs-end"></div><div id="mceu_140" class="mce-container mce-first mce-abs-layout-item mce-formitem" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" style="left: 20px; top: 20px; width: 445px; height: 30px;"><div id="mceu_140-body" class="mce-container-body mce-abs-layout" style="width: 445px; height: 30px;"><div id="mceu_140-absend" class="mce-abs-end"></div><label id="mceu_124-l" class="mce-widget mce-label mce-first mce-abs-layout-item" for="mceu_124" aria-disabled="false" style="line-height: 16px; left: 0px; top: 7px; width: 143px; height: 16px;">Source</label><div id="mceu_124" class="mce-combobox mce-last mce-abs-layout-item mce-has-open" style="left: 143px; top: 0px; width: 302px; height: 30px;"><input id="mceu_124-inp" class="mce-textbox mce-placeholder" value="" hidefocus="1" spellcheck="false" aria-labelledby="mceu_124-l" style="width: 259px;"><div id="mceu_124-open" class="mce-btn mce-open" tabindex="-1" role="button"><button id="mceu_124-action" type="button" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-browse"></i></button></div></div></div></div><div id="mceu_141" class="mce-container mce-abs-layout-item mce-formitem" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" style="left: 20px; top: 60px; width: 445px; height: 30px;"><div id="mceu_141-body" class="mce-container-body mce-abs-layout" style="width: 445px; height: 30px;"><div id="mceu_141-absend" class="mce-abs-end"></div><label id="mceu_125-l" class="mce-widget mce-label mce-first mce-abs-layout-item" for="mceu_125" aria-disabled="false" style="line-height: 16px; left: 0px; top: 7px; width: 143px; height: 16px;">Image description</label><input id="mceu_125" class="mce-textbox mce-last mce-abs-layout-item" value="" hidefocus="1" aria-labelledby="mceu_125-l" style="left: 143px; top: 0px; width: 292px; height: 28px;"></div></div><div id="mceu_142" class="mce-container mce-last mce-abs-layout-item mce-formitem" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" style="left: 20px; top: 100px; width: 445px; height: 30px;"><div id="mceu_142-body" class="mce-container-body mce-abs-layout" style="width: 445px; height: 30px;"><div id="mceu_142-absend" class="mce-abs-end"></div><label id="mceu_126-l" class="mce-widget mce-label mce-first mce-abs-layout-item" for="mceu_126" aria-disabled="false" style="line-height: 16px; left: 0px; top: 7px; width: 143px; height: 16px;">Dimensions</label><div id="mceu_126" class="mce-container mce-last mce-abs-layout-item" aria-labelledby="mceu_126-l" style="left: 143px; top: 0px; width: 302px; height: 30px;"><div id="mceu_126-body" class="mce-container-body mce-abs-layout" style="width: 302px; height: 30px;"><div id="mceu_126-absend" class="mce-abs-end"></div><input id="mceu_127" class="mce-textbox mce-first mce-abs-layout-item" value="" hidefocus="1" maxlength="5" size="3" aria-label="Width" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 51px; height: 28px;"><label id="mceu_128" class="mce-widget mce-label mce-abs-layout-item" style="line-height: 16px; left: 66px; top: 7px; width: 7px; height: 16px;">x</label><input id="mceu_129" class="mce-textbox mce-abs-layout-item" value="" hidefocus="1" maxlength="5" size="3" aria-label="Height" style="left: 78px; top: 0px; width: 51px; height: 28px;"><div id="mceu_130" class="mce-checkbox mce-checked mce-last mce-abs-layout-item" unselectable="on" aria-labelledby="mceu_130-al" tabindex="-1" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" style="left: 144px; top: 6px; width: 158px; height: 18px;"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-checkbox"></i><span id="mceu_130-al" class="mce-label">Constrain proportions</span></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div id="mceu_131" class="mce-container mce-form mce-last mce-abs-layout-item" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="mceu_122-t1" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 485px; height: 150px; display: none;"><div id="mceu_131-body" class="mce-container-body mce-abs-layout" style="width: 485px; height: 150px;"><div id="mceu_131-absend" class="mce-abs-end"></div><div id="mceu_143" class="mce-container mce-first mce-abs-layout-item mce-formitem" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" style="left: 20px; top: 20px; width: 445px; height: 30px;"><div id="mceu_143-body" class="mce-container-body mce-abs-layout" style="width: 445px; height: 30px;"><div id="mceu_143-absend" class="mce-abs-end"></div><label id="mceu_132-l" class="mce-widget mce-label mce-first mce-abs-layout-item" for="mceu_132" aria-disabled="false" style="line-height: 16px; left: 0px; top: 7px; width: 61px; height: 16px;">Style</label><input id="mceu_132" class="mce-textbox mce-last mce-abs-layout-item" value="" hidefocus="1" aria-labelledby="mceu_132-l" style="left: 61px; top: 0px; width: 374px; height: 28px;"></div></div><div id="mceu_133" class="mce-container mce-form mce-last mce-abs-layout-item" style="left: 20px; top: 60px; width: 445px; height: 70px;"><div id="mceu_133-body" class="mce-container-body mce-abs-layout" style="width: 445px; height: 70px;"><div id="mceu_133-absend" class="mce-abs-end"></div><div id="mceu_144" class="mce-container mce-first mce-abs-layout-item mce-formitem" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 186px; height: 30px;"><div id="mceu_144-body" class="mce-container-body mce-abs-layout" style="width: 186px; height: 30px;"><div id="mceu_144-absend" class="mce-abs-end"></div><label id="mceu_134-l" class="mce-widget mce-label mce-first mce-abs-layout-item" for="mceu_134" aria-disabled="false" style="line-height: 16px; left: 0px; top: 7px; width: 136px; height: 16px;">Vertical space</label><input id="mceu_134" class="mce-textbox mce-last mce-abs-layout-item" value="" hidefocus="1" aria-labelledby="mceu_134-l" style="left: 136px; top: 0px; width: 40px; height: 28px;"></div></div><div id="mceu_145" class="mce-container mce-abs-layout-item mce-formitem" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" style="left: 259px; top: 0px; width: 186px; height: 30px;"><div id="mceu_145-body" class="mce-container-body mce-abs-layout" style="width: 186px; height: 30px;"><div id="mceu_145-absend" class="mce-abs-end"></div><label id="mceu_135-l" class="mce-widget mce-label mce-first mce-abs-layout-item" for="mceu_135" aria-disabled="false" style="line-height: 16px; left: 0px; top: 7px; width: 136px; height: 16px;">Horizontal space</label><input id="mceu_135" class="mce-textbox mce-last mce-abs-layout-item" value="" hidefocus="1" aria-labelledby="mceu_135-l" style="left: 136px; top: 0px; width: 40px; height: 28px;"></div></div><div id="mceu_146" class="mce-container mce-last mce-abs-layout-item mce-formitem" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" style="left: 0px; top: 40px; width: 186px; height: 30px;"><div id="mceu_146-body" class="mce-container-body mce-abs-layout" style="width: 186px; height: 30px;"><div id="mceu_146-absend" class="mce-abs-end"></div><label id="mceu_136-l" class="mce-widget mce-label mce-first mce-abs-layout-item" for="mceu_136" aria-disabled="false" style="line-height: 16px; left: 0px; top: 7px; width: 136px; height: 16px;">Border</label><input id="mceu_136" class="mce-textbox mce-last mce-abs-layout-item" value="" hidefocus="1" aria-labelledby="mceu_136-l" style="left: 136px; top: 0px; width: 40px; height: 28px;"></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: `$('.mce-first :text:first').attr('id')`

Comment: That's because the input is not a child of .mce-container-body.  You need to use the find function instead of the child function.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong selector because:

1)  `window.parent` returns window element object and then you tried using jquery selector with incorrect syntax along with it.

2) There is no child selector in jquery.

You can rather use:

```
$(window.parent).find(".mce-container-body input:first").attr("id");
```

if you want to get the id of all inputs in array:

```
 $(window.parent).find(".mce-container-body input").map(function(){
     return this.id;
 }).get();
```

Comment: its not accesible because its defined in iframe which is in turn rendered in main html tag... please check html layout as mentioned in the above code.

Comment: sorry the above code is still not working, may be there is some error in  my question. I have updated my question and provided the browser version of code...

Comment: I think its not possible because in actual html page,  there are a lot of jquery plugin files related to it. The above code  is just a code snipet for making question more understandable.